# Looping through data to set values > or < variable as NA in R

Tags: r, loops, na

I have a data frame containing columns with integers, characters, and numerics. The actual data set is much larger than the example given below, but what is below is a passable and much smaller imitation.

I am trying to loop through the data and change any values greater than the `mean + (3 * standard deviation)` and less than the `mean - (3 * standard deviation)` to `NA` in the numeric columns **only**. If a column contains an integer or character, the loop should skip it and continue onto the next column. Additionally, most columns already contain some `NA` values and will have lots of values that fall within the `mean +/- (3*sd)`. Those values need to remain as they are.

The ultimate goal of this script is to use it on future data sets with the same structure and while I am open to suggestions with packages, I would like to use loops if possible. However, I am far from an expert in R and will happily take any and all advice anyone has for me!

I have worked out a structure for the overall script, but it stops after the first `next` statement.

The script:

```
data = data.frame(test_data)

for (i in colnames(data)){
  if (class(data$i) == "numeric"){
    m = mean(data$i, na.rm=TRUE)
    sd = sd(data$i, na.rm=TRUE)
  }
    else
      next
  for (j in 1:nrow(data)){
    if (data$i[j,] > (m + 3*sd)){
      data$i[j,] <- NA
    }
    else if (data$i[j,] < (m - 3*sd)){
      data$i[j,] <- NA
    }
    else 
      next
    }
}
```

The data being used to test this script is as follows:

```
Trait1 = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.35, 1.1, 1.2, NA, 1000, 1.5, 1.4, 1.6)
Trait2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
Trait3 = c(125.1, 119.3, 118.4, NA, 1.1, 122.3, 123.4, 125.7, 121.5, 121.7)
test_data = data.frame(Trait1, Trait2, Trait3)
```

Thank you in advance for any help you have to offer, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: None of your example values get replaced using that criteria as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and converting the numeric variables to a z-score using `scale()`, this can be simplified to:

```
library(dplyr)

test_data %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace(.x, abs(scale(.x)) > 3, NA))
```

Comment: `scale` is the key to this.

Comment: @thelatemail - You're right that deserves an explicit mention.  Edited.

Comment: Base R translation of this: `nums <- sapply(test_data, is.numeric);
test_data[nums][(!is.na(test_data[nums])) & abs(scale(test_data[nums])) > 3] <- 0`

Comment: I like this solution a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution **without** any loop (sorry:)) using `map_df` function from `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)

Trait1 = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.35, 1.1, 1.2, NA, 1000, 1.5, 1.4, 1.6)
Trait2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
Trait3 = c(125.1, 119.3, 118.4, NA, 1.1, 122.3, 123.4, 125.7, 121.5, 121.7)
test_data = data.frame(Trait1, Trait2, Trait3)

map_df(test_data,function(x) {
  if(class(x) == "numeric"){
    x[x <= (mean(x,na.rm = T) - 3*sd(x,na.rm = T)) | x>= (mean(x,na.rm = T) + 3*sd(x,na.rm = T))] = NA      
  }
  return(x)
}
)
```

If you want your `mean` and `sd` calculation to be with `NA`, change `na.rm = T` into `na.rm = F`.

**NB:** Pay attention to the fact that in this case you do not have any value greater or smaller than mean minus or plus three standard deviations. If you were thinking that `1000` in column `Trait1` was your "suspicious" point, then think again as it is not greater than `mean +3*sd`. I recommend testing on a different dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a loop, the following should work:

```
for (i in colnames(data)){
  if (class(data[,i]) == "numeric"){
    m = mean(data[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
    sd = sd(data[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
    for (j in 1:nrow(data)){
      if (is.na(data[j,i])==F&(data[j,i] > (m + 3*sd)|data[j,i] < (m - 3*sd))){
        data[j,i] <- NA
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is mostly just a slimmed-down version of what you wrote, but the key differences are that 1) writing `data$i` where `i` is a string specifying a column name does not work and 2) if you don't specify that you need `data[j,]` to not be `NA`, then you may get an error when you try to run things like `data[j,i] > (m + 3*sd)`. The other point, which is more stylistic, is that you don't strictly need to include all the `else` statements. In particular, you can just include the `for(j in...)` statement directly under the `if(class...=="numeric")` clause, without `else next`, because `else next` just forces it to not run the rest if `class!="numeric"`, but you've already specified that `class` is `"numeric"`, so you don't need to specify that again. Hope that makes sense and is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of things, I've been using `base::ifelse()` in conjunction with the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(tidylog)

test_data %<>%

  # Mutate any variable if (and only if) it's numeric...
  mutate_if(is.numeric,

            # ...then, if it meets the following criteria...
            ~ ifelse(
              test = .x > mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE) + 3 * sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE) |
                     .x < mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE) - 3 * sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE) |
                     .x %>% is.na,

              # ...replace with NA. If it doesn't...
              yes = NA,

              # ...leave as is!
              no  = .x

            ))
```

Note the lambda function above, using `~`  and `.x`.

Echoing what Vitali said above, this code didn't change anything in the dummy data. To make absolutely sure, I loaded in `tidylog`, which is a neat package that prints dataframe changes due to tidyverse functions whenever they are run.

**Edit:** thanks to Vitali for pointing out that the original code was not generalizable. I've also removed a lot of the fluff.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code is not generalisable for future (and unknown) dataset since with unknown data you wouldn't know that `Trait2 ` is not `numeric` .